# How to pass Data from express to .ejs file while redirecting in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have on login form in login.ejs file when i click on submit after filling information i am redirecting to the page if detail are correct otherwise i want to show something in .ejs that password is wrong.Below are the detail

Here is my app.js file code- Here i am sending one json and hiding that invalid password in .ejs file

```
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {

     res.render("login",{Error:"none"});

});

app.post('/login', function (req, res) {

    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
     //Here will be my code to check detail wrong or right
     res.redirect('/',{Error:'block'});
}
```

Here is my login.ejs file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font.css" type="text/css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="Error" id="error" style="display:<%=Error%>;">Invalid email/phone or password</div>
    <div class="Body">
        <form class="LogBox" action="/login" method="post">
            <div class="Head">Log In</div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email or Phone" class="inputfrontbutton" name="username">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password"  class="inputfrontbutton" name="password">
                <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="frontsubmit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But I am unable to send json data in redirect.Is there any way i can do this?

Comment: Do you mean the `Error` is not being passed and displayed in your `login.ejs` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to express [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect) of .redirect method:

> res.redirect([status,] path)
>
> Redirects to the URL derived from the specified path, with specified status, a positive integer that corresponds to an HTTP status code . If not specified, status defaults to “302 “Found”.

So you can't call it like that:

```
res.redirect('/',{Error:'block'});
```

Even if that method work, it'll just redirect to `'/'`, which will trigger the `app.get('/', function (req, res) {...}` endpoint and show the initial login page, with error message hidden.

I believe, the best way it to change last line in `app.post('/login', function (req, res) {...}` to

```
res.render("login",{Error:"block"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a redirection after an AJAX call if you're using AJAX. Use send instead

```
res.send({Error:'block'});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `json` with `res.render` method but to do with `res.redirect` you can use following.

1. You can use `encodeURIComponent` 
   `app.get('/user', function(req, res) {
   var error = encodeURIComponent('error');
   res.redirect('/?user=' + error);
   });`
2. Another way is using something in the session. [Link to setup Sessions](https://blog.xervo.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions)
   `req.session['error'] = "Error";`

   `req.redirect('/');`
3. You can also use `express-flash` to flash any error on page [Basic example an Usage of express-flash](https://github.com/expressjs/express-messages)

Comment: Thank you so much for help :)