# Sending data object to another page using nodeJS and EJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

SI have an express server running. In the app.post ('/ login'), I have a data object that has a name and a password which i obtained from a form. I would like to forward this data to another EJS page.

**app.js** --> server

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const port = 3000 || process.env.PORT;

app.use(express.json());

//Set the views + engine
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.render('about');
});


app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;

    res.render('about', {data: data}); //i want to send this data to the about page and priew it on the screen
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port: ${port}`);
})
```

**about.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Data</h1>
    <p><%= data %></p> <!--Preview to entred data from the user here-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i think i don't get any error but there is no redirect. I stay on the same page. If I open the netwerk tab and look at the response, i can see the about page with the acctual data. But the redirect isn't made

Comment: So you are getting the `{data:data}` that you're sending there right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass Data from express to .ejs file while redirecting in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609406/how-to-pass-data-from-express-to-ejs-file-while-redirecting-in-node-js)

Comment: @theWellHopeErr I get the `{data:data}` in the response of my network tab but on the accutal page not