# How to pass data from express to ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have server.js file with query:

```
app.get('/tasks', function(req, res) {
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY task_id ASC', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    console.log(results.rows[0]);
    res.render('pages/tasks', {data: results.rows});
  })
});
```

And in EJS file, where I would like to display data:

```
<main>
  <div>
    <h1>res: <% data %></h1>
  </div>
</main>
```

Unfortunately in EJS file variable ***data*** is empty while ***results.rows[0]*** in server.js file displays correct value.

How can I pass data from server.js to EJS file?

Comment: There are plenty of basic examples of how to do this in the EJS documentation.  I'd suggest you start there and then update your question with an example that looks like something there.  You can't just directly display an array like `results.rows`.  You would instead iterate that data in a loop and generate HTML for each iteration of the loop.  There are examples of this in the doc.  Please read it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass Data from express to .ejs file while redirecting in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609406/how-to-pass-data-from-express-to-ejs-file-while-redirecting-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing a "="

```
<%= data %>
```

and you have to iterate through data as its not a single data and if you wanna print a single data then pass only one data

```
res.render('pages/tasks', {data: results.rows[0]});
```