# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findAll')

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, sequelize.js, ejs

I'm trying to import data from my mysql database to my index.ejs file, but it keeps giving me several errors, I've tried to correct it and I couldn't, my index.ejs file is not recognizing the ejs syntax.

this is my file to generate the routes with express

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
const db = require('./models/db');
const path = require('path');

//para colocar conteúdo dinâminco no html
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');



//para utilizar arquivos estáticos no node (css, js)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public")));

//manda infos para o front
 app.get("/", async (req, res) => {

    try{
      const usuario = await db.usuario.findAll();

      res.render('index', { usuario });
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error('Erro ao buscar produtos:', error);
      res.status(500).send('Erro interno do servidor');
    }


 });

 //recebe infos e manda para o banco de dados
 app.post("/imput", async (req, resp) => {
   res.send
 })

 //se conecta a porta 8080 do localhost
 app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("servidor iniciado na porta 8080: http://localhost:8080");
 });
```

and this is my index.ejs

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cadastro</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://engixelevadores.com.br/public/template/assets/images/favicon/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/style.css">
   

    <script src="script.js"> </script>
        
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Cadastro</h1>

        <!--Forms de cadastro de infos dos clientes, utilizando de uma api para facilitar o preenchimento do endereço-->
        <form id="addresForm" action="/submit" method="post">

            <div class="infos1">

                <label for="codigo">Código: <br></label>
                <input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" required> 
                <br>

                <label for="nome">Nome: <br></label>
                <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" required>
                <br>

                <label for="cpf_cnpj">CPF/CNPJ: <br></label>
                <input type="number" name="cpf_cnpj" id="cpf_cnpj" placeholder="Apenas números">
                <br>

                <label for="pf_pj">Tipo: <br></label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="pf_pj" id="pf_pj" value="pf">
                    PF
                </label>
                
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="pf_pj" id="pf_pj" value="pj">
                    PJ
                    <br><br>
                </label>

                <label for="onde_encontrou_emp">Como conheceu a Engix? <br></label>

                <label for="onde_encontrou_emp">
                    <input type="radio" name="onde_encontrou_emp" id="onde_encontrou_emp" value="Indicação">
                    Indicação
                    <br>
                </label>

                <label for="onde_encontrou_emp">
                    <input type="radio" name="onde_encontrou_emp" id="onde_encontrou_emp" value="Redes Sociais">
                    Redes Sociais
                    <br>
                </label>

                <label for="onde_encontrou_emp">
                    <input type="radio" name="onde_encontrou_emp" id="onde_encontrou_emp" value="Google">
                    Google
                    <br>
                </label>

                <label for="onde_encontrou_emp">
                    <input type="radio" name="onde_encontrou_emp" id="onde_encontrou_emp" value="Google">
                    Comercial
                    <br>
                </label>

                <label for="onde_encontrou_emp">
                    <input type="radio" name="onde_encontrou_emp" id="onde_encontrou_emp" value="Outro">
                    Outros
                    <input type="text" name="onde_encontrou_emp" id="onde_encontrou_emp">
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="infos2">


                <!--Chama a function pesquisacep que está no arquivo script.js, ela fará a consulta em um banco de dados externo e autocompletará os campos abaixo-->
                <label for="cep">CEP: <br></label>
                <input type="text" name="cep" id="cep" size="15" maxlength="9" onblur="pesquisacep(this.value);" placeholder="Apenas números">
                <br>

                <label for="rua">Rua: <br></label>
                <input type="text" name="rua" id="rua" size="50">
                <br>

                <label for="numero">Numero: <br></label>
                <input type="text" name="numero" id="numero" size="50">
                <br>

                <label for="bairro">Bairro: <br></label>
                <input type="text" name="bairro" id="bairro" size="50">
                <br>

                <label for="cidade">Cidade: <br></label>
                <input type="text" name="cidade" id="cidade" size="50">
                <br>

                <label for="uf">UF: <br></label>
                <input type="text" name="uf" id="uf" size="50">

            </div>

            <div class="infos3">

                <label for="contato_cliente">Nome do contato: <br></label>
                <input type="text" name="contato_cliente" id="contato_cliente">
                <br>

                <label for="telefone">Nº Telefone fixo: <br></label>
                <input type="tel" name="telefone" id="telefone" placeholder="Apenas números">
                <br>

                <label for="celular">Nº Celular: <br></label>
                <input type="tel" name="celular" id="celular" placeholder="Apenas números">
                <br>

                <p>Se não houver DDD, ele será <br> definido automaticamente como (51)</p>
            </div>

            <div class="infos4">

                <label for="responsavel">Responsável:</label>

                <select name="responsavel" id="responsavel" autofocus >

                   ** <% usuario.forEach( => { %>
                        <option value="<%= usuario.id %>"><%= usuario.nome %></option>
                      <% }); %>**

                </select>
                
                <br>

                <label for="tipo_equipamento">Tipo de equipamento:</label>

                <select name="tipo_equipamento" id="tipo_equipamento" autofocus >
                    <option value="PNE">PNE</option>
                    <option value="Elevador Comercial">Elevador Comercial</option>
                    <option value="Elevador Residencial">Elevador Residencial</option>
                    <option value="Não informado">Não informado</option>
                </select>
                
                <br>

                <label for="tipo_equipamento">Tipo de equipamento:</label>

                <select name="tipo_equipamento" id="tipo_equipamento" autofocus >
                    <option value="PNE">PNE</option>
                    <option value="Elevador Comercial">Elevador Comercial</option>
                    <option value="Elevador Residencial">Elevador Residencial</option>
                    <option value="Não informado">Não informado</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </form>


    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

was for the data to be loaded in the select

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65977136/how-to-pass-data-from-express-to-ejs?

Comment: `<% usuario.forEach((user) => { %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you provided, it seems like you are trying to render the **index.ejs** file and pass the **usuario** data to it. However, it looks like there is an issue with the syntax in your **index.ejs** file where you're trying to iterate over the **usuario** array.

**Current**:

```
<% usuario.forEach( => { %>
    <option value="<%= usuario.id %>"><%= usuario.nome %></option>
<% }); %>
```

**Fixed**

```
<% usuario.forEach((user) => { %>
    <option value="<%= user.id %>"><%= user.nome %></option>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: Please do not answer typo-type questions. Comment with the issue and vote to close